# N-Gram, tf-idf and Cosine similarity in Perl

Tags: perl, similarity, tf-idf, n-gram

I am trying to do some pattern 'mining' in piece of multi word on each line. I have done the N-gram analysis using the Text::Ngrams module in perl which give me the frequency of each word . I am however quite confused about the finding patterns in this text.

The tf-idf finds frequency also I presume but how does this differ from the Ngram analysis that I did and how does the similarity measure also help.

Please are there any perl modules or  snippets of code I could get to understand some of this concepts .

Please I am from a physics  background but have to do some pattern recognizing so I am a little new to some of these , a good reference on this topics will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a bunch of N documents and you:

Want to find out if Document X (containing an article on how to be a bodybuilder) is similar to another Document Y whose contents you do not know.  If Document Y would be "similar" to Document X, it might contain the usual terms one associates with bodybuilding - eg: weight-lifting, barbells, dumbells and maybe Arnold.

So, the similarity of Document X, Document Y would be pretty high.  One way to measure this similarity, is using the Cosine Angle between these two documents.

Cosine Similarity Reference: http://www.miislita.com/information-retrieval-tutorial/cosine-similarity-tutorial.html

Use [CPAN to search](http://search.cpan.org/) for Perl modules. For eg, to compute cosine similarity you could try the [Text::Document](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aDocument) module